# Erro nos testes com Jest e Supertest

Tags: node.js, express.js, jest

Boa tarde, galera;

Criei meus testes com Jest e supertest, e eles estão dando um erro "Object.is equality",

```
Versão Node: 12.18.3
Versão NPM: 6.14.4
Versão Yarn: 1.22.4
```

ps: estou usando SQLite e Sequelize, além de estar utilizando Sucrase, e Express;

Minha configuração do Jest:

```js
module.exports = {
  // Stop running tests after `n` failures
  bail: 1,

  // Automatically clear mock calls and instances between every test
  clearMocks: true,

  // Indicates whether the coverage information should be collected while executing the test
  collectCoverage: true,

  // An array of glob patterns indicating a set of files for which coverage information should be collected
  collectCoverageFrom: ['src/app/**/*.js'],

  // The directory where Jest should output its coverage files
  coverageDirectory: '__tests__/coverage',

  // A list of reporter names that Jest uses when writing coverage reports
  coverageReporters: ['text', 'lcov'],

  // The test environment that will be used for testing
  testEnvironment: 'node',

  // The glob patterns Jest uses to detect test files
  testMatch: ['**/__tests__/**/*.test.js'],

  // A map from regular expressions to paths to transformers
  transform: {
    '.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)': '@sucrase/jest-plugin',
  },
};
```

meu mill.test.js:

```js
import request from 'supertest';
import server from '../../src/app';

describe('Mill Endpoints', () => {
  it('should be able to create a new mill', async () => {
    const response = await request(server)
      .post('/mills')
      .send({
        name: 'mill1',
      });
    expect(response.status).toBe(201);
    expect(response.body).toHaveProperty('id');
  });
});
```

Meu controller responsável pela criação:

```js
async createMill(request, response) {
    const millExists = await Mill.findOne({
      where: { name: request.body.name },
    });

    if (millExists) {
      return response.status(401).json({ error: 'Mill already exists' });
    }

    const { id, name } = await Mill.create(request.body);

    return response.status(201).json({ id, name });
  }
```

e meu validator:

```js
try {
    const schema = Yup.object().shape({
      name: Yup.string().min(5).max(15).required(),
    });

    await schema.validate(request.body, { abortEarly: false });

    return next();
  } catch ({ errors }) {
    return response.format({ type: 'validation', errors }, 400);
  }
```

[image: test error]

[image: sequelize err]

Answer (score 0):

Problema era na configuração do Sequelize pro SQLite, que não tinha configuração de underscored e underscoredAll